# How to run exchange powershell command automatically from batch file

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have a `.bat` file with the following code:

```
START C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -version 2.0 -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto"
```

The code above will successfully start a new powershell host and then connect to my exchange server.

How can I run the below command in the exchange powershell host, from the same `batch` file? (basically I am trying to automate the process)

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -resultsize unlimited -start "01/01/2020 00:00:00" -Server hermod -EventId Deliver | where {[string]$_.sender -like '*@gmail.com'} | where {[string]$_.Recipients -like '*@gmail.com'} > "C:\MailReporter\Output\emails.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out: I needed to use the `;` symbol after the first command to signal the end of the current command. I was then able to execute the next command without issue.

Full working code:

```
START C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -version 2.0 -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; Get-MessageTrackingLog -resultsize unlimited -start '01/09/2019 00:00:00' -Server hermod -EventId Deliver | where {[string]$_.sender -like '*@gmail.co.uk'} | where {[string]$_.Recipients -like '*@gmail.co.uk'} > 'C:\MailReporter\Output\emails.txt' "
```